# What does parameter bp_moment_scale mean in OpenCV's ANN?

Tags: opencv, neural-network

I understand **bp_dw_scale** is used for gradient decent step size, but how about **bp_moment_scale** ?

I have no idea what does it mean, could any one explain it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/neural_networks.html

> double bp_moment_scale Strength of the momentum term (the difference
>   between weights on the 2 previous iterations). This parameter provides
>   some inertia to smooth the random fluctuations of the weights. It can
>   vary from 0 (the feature is disabled) to 1 and beyond. The value 0.1
>   or so is good enough

Basically, this is your back propagation momentum value.  It allows the previous deltas to add momentum and help push through local minima.